The Mathematical Origins of Software Engineering
I learned in college that computer programming is a field of engineering with mathematics as its scientific field.  If computer programming is merely a subset of applied mathematics, then does that mean that most computer programs can be expressed as proofs by mathematical induction?
I wrote a simple program to illustrate this hypothesis:
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int factToFind)
{
    /**
     *  Base case: 0! = 1
     */
    if(factToFind == 0)
    {
         return 1;
    }
    /**
     * Inductive Assumption:  factorial(n - 1) is a decidable function.
     * Inductive Step: n! = n * factorial(n - 1) is an O(1) modification
     * to factorial(n), therefore it is also decidable.
     */
    return factToFind * factorial(factToFind - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* factToFindStr = argv[1];
    int factToFind = atoi(factToFindStr);
    cout << factorial(factToFind) << endl;
    return 0;
}


"I learned in college that computer programming is a field of engineering with mathematics as its scientific field." - sounds like a nonsensical approach.

This question is based on several false premises. Programming is not a field of engineering, but software engineering is - programming is a very, very small aspect of software engineering. Engineering fields do not necessarily have a specific scientific field that they draw upon. I don't know if these false premises have a bearing on the underlying question or not, but it's probably worth spending time to research and clarify the question.

Mathematics is far more than proofs, and there are more types of proofs than just "proofs by induction". So how in hell do you come to this strange conclusion? Moreover, computer programming is a subset of computer science. Whether CS is a subset of mathematics or if it is a field of its own depends mostly on the (opinionated) definition of what counts as mathematics and what not. For me, theoretical CS is clearly mathematics, and certain aspects of programming can be described using tools from theoretical CS, so there is some overlap, but CS and SWE have also non-mathematical aspects.


then does that mean that most computer programs can be expressed as proofs by mathematical induction

All computer programs are math. There is no getting around that.
But proofs? Sadly no. You aren't the first to try. The problem is working code is a super set of provable code. When we code we tend to make an unprovable mess. To combat that Dijkstra gave us structured programming (which is just forbidding/replacing/treating formally a troublesome little instruction: goto). Sadly, even with a language that enforces that we still write unprovable messes.
In some ways it not our fault. It has been proven that any system that can be self referential is hopeless to build proofs on. Thanks to the halting problem we can't even prove that our programs terminate.
So while we want to achieve correctness in many ways we're doomed to fall short.
What we've come to accept is that we should strive to write readable testable code. The proof thing just never worked out for us.

Your statement about  self-referential systems is not well suited to explain the differences between math and computer programs, since it applies to mathematical axiom systems as well.

@DocBrown My intent was to show that even "pure math" contends with unprovable expressions. So establishing that computer programs are math doesn't save us.
